# How to set a person/group field in UpdateListItems

Tags: workflow, 2007, web-services

I'm trying to use a web service call in Nintex Workflow to add a new item to a list.  I'm using the web service because the user only has read permissions to the list.  What syntax is needed to set the person/group field?

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1">
  <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
    <Field Name="Title">Hey there</Field>
    <Field Name="ContentType">Registration</Field>
    <Field Name="CourseID">{ItemProperty:CourseID}</Field>
    <Field Name="EmployeeEmail">{WorkflowVariable:userAccount}</Field>
  </Method>
</Batch>
```

I've tried passing in domain/account, id;#display_name, email address with no success.  If I omit the EmployeeEmail field from the batch command, the insert works fine.

Comment: Closed as off topic [as described here](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121/when-should-we-allow-questions-about-products-that-dont-belong-to-a-sharepoint-s/130#130). Please leave any comments about the closure you have there if desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id;#display_name seems to be the correct method, I found I was overwriting my variable someplace else, that was causing my batch command to fail.